# several servlet filter changing the response

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Think about using several filters to change response

f1 should debug the response, f2 should reformat the content and then f3 should compress it all.
I red almost all blogs about filters and the essentials from oracle, but always without success.

Problem 1: As I understand getWriter has to be called in any case to be able to write the changed response back to the original response.

This leads to the problem, that getWriter was already called -exception is thrown in the chain.

Problem 2: Is it necessary to write the response even if was not changed? 
Think about a condition which let the response in the filter unchanged.

I try to show what I am doing right now in a kind of pseudo code

```
  //VERSION 01:
         doFilter(){
            if (condition to change response is true){
               Printwriter out = response.getWriter();
               OutputStreamResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new OutputStreamResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);
               doFilter(originalRequest,wrappedResponse);
               String convertedResponse = convertResponse(wrappedResponse.getContent());
               out.write(convertedResponse);
               out.close(); // without this it seems not to be send to the client??       
            }else{
              doFilter(originalRequest,originalRequest);  
            }
        }
 //VERSION 02:
         doFilter(){
            Printwriter out = response.getWriter();
            OutputStreamResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new OutputStreamResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);
            doFilter(originalRequest,wrappedResponse);
            if (condition to change response is true){
               String convertedResponse = convertResponse(wrappedResponse.getContent());
               out.write(convertedResponse);
            }else{
               out.write(wrappedResponse.getContent());              
            }
            out.close(); // without this it seems not to be send to the client??       

        }
```

Now  call 3 of these filters after each other with different conversions. I always get the "getWriter already called"-Exception.

I don't understand, because I pass always a wrapped response-object? 
Perhaps somebody has a hint what is totally wrong with my approach. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The Wall of Text (TM) approach to asking questions rarely garners useful responses. If a paragraph is longer than 3 lines long, it's next to impossible to read. I, for one, don't bother...

Comment: Hi Boris, ok, good hint, I don't use this forums often, but I reorganized my question a little

Comment: If you want to intercept the servlet response and fiddle with it, you need still send the content at the end even if you don't fiddle with it. You have placed a filter on the data pipeline back to the client, and aren't letting data through otherwise. You always need to `flush()` the response back to the client otherwise serverside buffers won't be sent, `close() ` calls `flush()`. The servlet will do this itself, but as you are filtering the pipeline, the servlet flushes your wrapper rather than the actual data stream.

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for the response, but when I use Version01 no wrapper is used when no conversion is done, so no need to flush anything in this case? How can I get rid of the already getWriter called-Exception, when calling response.getWriter() in all filters again?

Comment: You cannot. You need to ensure that your `Filter` is the first to call that.

Comment: Ok, calling getWriter() seams to be a problem. I think about the situation, that there are several filters I take from given libs. They might all call getWriter() independent of each other. How does the spec mean to deal with that? Each filter should be able to be independent of others, but this seems not to be the case.

Comment: If you read the documentation you will see that the issue is that you are only allowed to call `getOutputStream` **or** `getWriter`. If you are getting an error them something else is calling `getOutputStream`...